# I'm using SendMail function from Microsoft Graph API but i'm getting an error that is unclear

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sendmail

I want to send a mail with my personal microsoft account, but Im getting the following error.
Im using my personal Microsoft account and Ive created the application permission for SendMail in Azure.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Content type text/html does not have a factory registered to be parsed
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization.ParseNodeFactoryRegistry.GetRootParseNode(String contentType, Stream content)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.GetRootParseNode(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.ThrowIfFailedResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, Activity activityForAttributes)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(RequestInformation requestInfo, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.SendNoContentAsync(RequestInformation requestInfo, Dictionary`2 errorMapping, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailRequestBuilder.PostAsync(SendMailPostRequestBody body, Action`1 requestConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at OrthoSystemsTool.Data.MailService.SendAsync(String toAddress, String subject) in C:\Files\Private\OrthoSytemsTool\OrthoSystemsTool\Data\MailService.cs:line 73
```

The MailService method is

```
public async Task<bool> SendAsync(string toAddress, string subject)
        {
            try
            {

                // The client credentials flow requires that you request the
                // /.default scope, and preconfigure your permissions on the
                // app registration in Azure. An administrator must grant consent
                // to those permissions beforehand.
                var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

                // Multi-tenant apps can use "common",
                // single-tenant apps must use the tenant ID from the Azure portal
                var tenantId = _configuration.GetSection("AAD")["TenantId"];

                // Values from app registration
                var clientId = _configuration.GetSection("AAD")["ClientId"];
                var clientSecret = _configuration.GetSection("AAD")["ClientSecret"];

                // using Azure.Identity;
                var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
                {
                    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                };

                // https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential
                var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

                var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
                {
                    Message = new Message
                    {
                        Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                        Body = new ItemBody
                        {
                            ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                            Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
                        },
                        ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
        {
            new Recipient
            {
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                {
                    Address = toAddress,
                },
            },
        },
                      
                    },
                    SaveToSentItems = false,
                };

                await graphClient.Users[_configuration.GetSection("MailService")["From"]].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I cannot find anything about this in the documentation, and I did everything as decribed.. I cannot use the Me instead of Users because Im using a registered application with client credentials.
Anyone knows whats wrong here?

Ive tried to use the graph proxy but it only say its "passed through" the api.

I want to send a mail but im getting an error